# OpenNLP NameFinder Custom Feature generation

Tags: java, machine-learning, opennlp, named-entity-recognition

I would like to train a own model to use in `OpenNLP NameFinder`.

Searched a lot and finally came up with a working code to train a model, but its not accurate. The documentation also says you need 15000 sentences to have a accurate model.

So you need to have 15000 sentences with a good context and at the name every time `<START> <END>`. To do this you would have to spend hours
days/months writing a `.txt file.`

I did some futher search to train a model without writing all by your self and came on `Custom Feature generation of OpenNLP`.
http://opennlp.apache.org/docs/1.8.1/manual/opennlp.html#tools.namefind.training.tool

But it says not much about how to use it. The documentation gives this :

```
AdaptiveFeatureGenerator featureGenerator = new CachedFeatureGenerator(
     new AdaptiveFeatureGenerator[]{
       new WindowFeatureGenerator(new TokenFeatureGenerator(), 2, 2),
       new WindowFeatureGenerator(new TokenClassFeatureGenerator(true), 2, 2),
       new OutcomePriorFeatureGenerator(),
       new PreviousMapFeatureGenerator(),
       new BigramNameFeatureGenerator(),
       new SentenceFeatureGenerator(true, false)
       });
```

Does somebody knows how to use this? Or much better, is someone already successful to train his own model for `OpenNLP NER` without typing him self the data set?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You still need annotated training text. The feature generators are used during the training to create a better model. Unfortunately, there is no substitute for annotated training text.

Comment: Any idea how to get annotated text without typing myself 15.000 sentences  with a good context?

Comment: How to collect your training depends on your domain. What kind of natural language text do you want to process? There is [this book](https://www.amazon.com/Natural-Language-Annotation-Machine-Learning/dp/1449306667) which helps you to understand how the collection and annotation process should work. If you need to create custom NER models, [this project](https://git.noc.fh-aachen.de/marc.schreiber/Towards-Effective-NLP-Application-Development) can help you to create your models. Currently, we are working on annotating NEs and it should be done in the next couple of weeks.

Comment: Thanks for the information, I'm interessed in the results of your project.

Comment: @Patrick, I released a beta version of my project. Do you want to test the project in order to train your custom NER model? I'm happy to give you some advice. We could arrange a chat so I can demonstrate the framework to you. ;-)